# Let $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $S$. Show: $\lim_{n\to \infty}||f_n||_S=||f||_S$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

> Let $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $S$. Show: $\lim_{n\to \infty}||f_n||_S=||f||_S$. $||f||_S=sup_S|S|$

My attempt:
since $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$, we have:
$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that } |f-f_n|<\epsilon \forall n>N$$

Now,
\begin{align}
|||f_n||-||f|||&=|\sup_S|f_n|-\sup_S|f||\\
&\leq |\sup_S|f_n|-\inf_S|f||\\
&=|\sup_S|f_n|+\sup_S-|f||\\
&=|\sup_S|f_n|-|f||\\
&\leq|\sup_S|f_n-f||\\
&\leq|\sup_S\epsilon|=\epsilon, n>N\\
&\implies\lim_{n\to \infty}||f_n||_S=||f||_S
\end{align}

Comment: $$\sup_S \lvert f_n\rvert-\sup_S \lvert f\rvert\neq \sup_S (\lvert f_n\rvert-\lvert f\rvert) $$

Comment: @Michael Lee its wrong even for sets. I corrected my proof.

Comment: What is $\|\cdot\|_S$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Carlos Santos $||f||_s=\sup_s|f|$

Comment: Why would you assume $\lvert \sup_S \lvert f_n\rvert-\sup_S \lvert f\rvert\rvert\leq \lvert \sup_S \lvert f_n\rvert-\inf_S \lvert f\rvert\rvert $? Consider $f_n\equiv 0$ for some $n $. Then, your inequality becomes $\sup_S \lvert f\rvert\leq \inf_S \lvert f\rvert$, which is absurd unless $f $ is constant on $S $.

Comment: @MichaelLee $\sup_S|f|\geq\inf_S|f|\implies \sup_S|f|-\sup_S|f|\leq \sup_S|f|-\inf_S|f|$

Comment: Yes, but $a\leq b $ doesn't imply  $\lvert a\rvert\leq \lvert b\rvert $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $f$, there is a natural $p$ such that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(\forall x\in S):n\geqslant p\implies|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon.$$Therefore$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):n\geqslant p\implies\|f_n-f\|_S\leqslant\varepsilon.$$But $\bigl|\|f_n\|_S-\|f\|_S\bigr|\leqslant\|f_n-f\|_S$, since$$\|f_n\|_S=\|f_n-f+f\|_S\leqslant\|f_n-f\|_S+\|f\|_S\implies\|f_n\|_S-\|f\|_S\leqslant\|f_n-f\|_S$$and$$\|f\|_S=\|f-f_n+f_n\|_S\leqslant\|f-f_n\|_S+\|f_n\|_S\implies\|f\|_S-\|f_n\|_S\leqslant\|f_n-f\|_S.$$Therefore$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):n\geqslant p\implies\bigl|\|f_n\|_S-\|f\|_S\bigr|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$What this means is that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_S=\|f\|_S.$$

Comment: Since $\lvert \| f_n\|_S-\|f\|_S\rvert \leq \|f_n-f\|_S $ was where the asker appeared to be stuck, it might be helpful to mention that this is a direct result of the triangle inequality and is often called the "reverse triangle inequality."

Comment: @MichaelLee Excellent suggestion! I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Follows of  triangular inequalities, that $| |f(x)| - |f_n(x)|| \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)|$, $\forall x$, we have that

$$|f(x)| - |f_n(x)| \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)|$$

and therefore

$$ - |f_n(x)| \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f(x)|$$

and so

$$ - |f_n(x)| \leq \|f - f_n\|_S + \|f\|_S.$$ 
Then 
$$ \|f\|_S \leq \|f - f_n\|_S + \|f_n\|_S.$$

Therefore

$$ \|f\|_S -  \|f_n\|_S\leq \|f - f_n\|_S .$$
Analogously, we can show that

$$ \|f_n\|_S -  \|f\|_S\leq \|f - f_n\|_S $$
 and therefore
$$ 0\leq |\|f_n\|_S -  \|f\|_S|\leq \|f - f_n\|_S $$

Doing $n \to \infty$, we heve proofed.